# Google Chrome PDF Viewer API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf.js

I do have a pdf `embeded` in to the page. It does work and it has it's own buttons, like print, download, rotate, zoom-in, zoom-out.

Is it possible to control these buttons from `javascript`? I want to show the pdf, but the buttons for download and print I want to control by myslef, with different design and placements outside of the `embeded` element.

TO sum up, I want to hide all buttons which is shown to the user from the default pdf viewer, except the page number, and I want to separately create `donwload` and `print` button with my own design but with the same functionality.

I've done a little bit of research and I found this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135146
which is yet has unknown status. Does it mean the API for Chrome pdf viewer doesnt exist? I couldnt fine any.

Another solution is to integrate PDF.js in my own web app, which is heavy (almost 2.6mb zipped) and time consuming.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, but you are stating that Chrome cannot do what you want and you don't want spend time on building the solution on top of PDF.js. I guess answer will be spend time and use PDF.js :)

Comment: @async5, actually I've found a way to do what I want. But it's hackish way, and I dont really like it. As I said, it's the web application, and I dont want a  user to download 2.6mb libs in addition to what my current page has. The system should run on DSL connection, which are low and has a lot of disconnects... so PDF.js is not an option. I just though there are an API but seems not.